# Dealing with temporal autocorrelation in logistic models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, autocorrelation

I sampled a bat species 3 days a month for 2 and a half years.

For each sampling day, I recorded in a spreadsheet whether the species

- was captured (1), or
- not (0).

Now, I want to investigate whether the temperature, the rain and the moon phase influence the probability of capture. However, I  imagine that my data is temporally autocorrelated, since collections on consecutive days and on consecutive months tend not to be independent.

How would you handle it on R? Would it be correct to add the “day of the year” as an independent glm variable?

Example: `glm (capture ~ temp + prec + lunar + day, data=mydata, family=binomial())`

I read something about “gls” being more appropriate in this case, but I don't know if that is correct and how to specify autocorrelation in this case.

Comment: I think that adding day of year is perfectly cromulent way of doing so, but be careful:  if it's too heavily correlated with temperature, it'll become difficult to interpret marginal effects.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide; [http://www-personal.umich.edu/~franzese/CarterSignorino.2010.BackToTheFuture.BeckReply.CSrejoinder.pdf](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Efranzese/CarterSignorino.2010.BackToTheFuture.BeckReply.CSrejoinder.pdf)

You effectively just have to create your time variable, square it, and then cube it, and add them all in.